# JavaFx application. Right side black

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have eclipse v4.8.0 and JavaFx SceneBuilder v8.5.0, JDK 1.8 and Windows 7 x86.
When I try to run my project it has black rect in the right side of window. Its size changes with window width (in picture the biggest size of black area). I tryed to wrap it in anchor pane but it wasn't help.

[JavaFx window with black right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msFNN.png)

I also changed a screen resolution but it also hasn't brought a solution.

---

At first i created a **new javaFx project**, then I added **FXML file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Accordion maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171">
  <panes>
    <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 1">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </TitledPane>
    <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 2">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </TitledPane>
    <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 3">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </TitledPane>
  </panes>
</Accordion>
```

In **scenebuilder** and in java programm i see [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlMQC.png).

Comment: Yes, please include how you are creating the scene (FXML). Even better, create a [mcve]. Also, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: I just ran your `FXML` and I didn't have any problems.